# Which one is safer to use in OOP?

Tags: php, pdo

I learned these 2 methods in PDO with OOP when I study it and I would like to ask which is safer to use? binding everything we used or just using ? and execute it.

1:

```
    public function query($query) {
  $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
      switch(true){
        case is_int($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
            break;
        case is_bool($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
            break;
        case is_null($value):
            $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
            break;
            default:
            $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute(){
  return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function lastInsertId(){
  $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}
```

or 2:

```
    public function insertRow($query, $params = []){
  try {
      $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute($params);
      return TRUE;
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      throw new Exception($e->getMessage()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: In the second example all params are treated as `PDO::PARAM_STR`.

Comment: in both cases queries are prepared, so there is no difference on this point regarding sql injection attacks.

Comment: The first one is simply wrong. You should never bind based on the type of the value. You should bind based on the type of the column.

Comment: currently using 2. one in my project in future probably I will change the method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use both but using bind it could be better with writing all with types instead using switch and to make it short you can use 2.

```
public function query($query, $params = []){
    global $datab
    $stmt = $datab->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Comment: using `global` makes no sense in this context. this function is a class method that already has a connection handle in the class variable

Answer (score 2):

The second one is much better, but still there is a cargo cult `catch`. And it doesn't return anything. Should be

```
public function query($query, $params = []){
    $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

an it can be used for any query, not only insert, but also select, update, delete and so on.