# PHP OOP binding problem inside the method

Tags: php, pdo

I try so hard to create this method with prepare, bind, and execute inside the class. But I guess I don't have enough knowledge about it whatever I do I couldn't make it work. I'm looking google for hours. I know that below code is wrong about binding but Can someone show me the correct way to do **binding inside this method?**

```
class User {

    protected static $db_table = "users";
    protected static $db_table_fields = array('username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name');
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    protected function properties() {

        $properties = array();
        foreach (static::$db_table_fields as $db_field) {
            if (property_exists($this, $db_field)) {  
                $properties[$db_field] = $this->$db_field;
            }
        }
        return $properties;
    }


    protected function clean_properties() {
        global $database;

        $clean_properties = array();
        foreach ($this->properties() as $key => $value) {
            $clean_properties[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $clean_properties;
    }


    public function create($params= []){
        global $database;
        $properties = $this->clean_properties();
        $fields =  ":" . implode("',:'", static::$db_table_fields);

        $sql= "INSERT INTO " .static::$db_table . "(" . implode(",", array_keys($properties)) . ")
        VALUES('". $fields ."')";
        $stmt = $database->prepare($sql);
        foreach ($fields as $field => &$params) {
            $stmt->bindValue($field, $params);
        }
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $this->id = $database->InsertId();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than binding - have you tried `if ($stmt->execute($fields)) {`

Comment: @NigelRen if I just pass $fields in execute, how will I pass trough $params=[ ] ?

Comment: There's no need to use `&` in the `foreach` if you're using `bindValue`.

Comment: `foreach ($fields as $field => &$params)` makes no sense. `$fields` is a string, not an array.

Comment: And `$params` is the function parameter, why are you using it as an iteration variable?

Comment: I think you want something like `foreach($params as $field => $value)`

Comment: What's the difference between `properties()` and `clean_properties()`? It looks like `clean_properties()` simply copying the array returned by `properties()`.

Comment: @riverhorse You can use `$stmt->execute($params)`

Comment: Don't you already have [a query method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680959/which-one-is-safer-to-use-in-oop) in your database class? Why don't you use it, just `$database->query($sql, $params);`?

Comment: @Barmar you are right. I did like you said I guess i have a problem with VALUES when I use ?,? something like this, it inserts but when I use it like in the code it doesn't insert.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I know, I'm trying to learn more with different coding styles.

Comment: @Barmar can you check my new code below?

Answer (score 0):

So I made my code like this for binding. I don't know if it is the correct way. I know I keep changing stuff. I guess it is the best way to learn to try different stuff.

```
//$param = array('x'=>$x, 'y'=>$y);
public function bind($param = [], $type=NULL){
  foreach($param as $key=>&$value){
    if (is_null($type)) {
      switch (true) {
        case is_int($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
          break;
        case is_bool($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
          break;
        case is_null($value):
          $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
          break;
        default:
          $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
      }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue(':'.$key,$value);
  }
  return $this->stmt;
}
```

Comment: You're not using `$type` in the call to `bindValue()`

Comment: There's no need to use a reference variable `&$value`

Comment: If you're not sure if this is right, it should be in the question, not an answer.

Comment: thank you. they are not allowing me to ask a question I have no idea why

Comment: I mean you should edit your original question and add this to it.

Comment: I didn't even think about it. I will keep in my mind next time :)